# Glimpse sql tab not enabled

Tags: entity-framework, glimpse

Have installed:

- Glimpse 1.8.6
- Glimpse.Ado 1.7.3
- Glimpse.AspNet 1.9.2
- Glimpse.EF6 1.6.5
- Glimpse.Mvc5 1.5.3

in an MVC5 project using EF 6.1.3

I create my connection with a simple `using (var db = new DbModel())` where `DbModel` inherits from `DbContext`.

I have confirmed that my connection string contains `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Any thoughts on why the sql tab is not enabled?

Comment: Hi, did you found the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The way you create your context does not *use* the Glimpse hooks that were put in place. You should make sure that you create your connections by using the `DBProviderFactories` like `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient");` for instance.

More details can be found [here](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Manual-ADO-Integration) on the Glimpse website

Comment: I haven't had to do anything special in other projects that use EF and Glimpse. However, I believe they are older versions of EF.

Comment: do you see any kind of error messages inside the glimpse log? ([see here on how to enable logging](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Configuration))

Comment: Turned on trace logging and did not get any errors. There are two warning lines about "Failed to load type when getting types from assembly Kendo.Mvc"

Comment: I have ecact same problem with same technologies. Is there any problems with Mvc 5 or EF6? I have been able to get glimpse working in the past?